# 406 error not acceptable,openwysiwyg_v1.4.7 while image selection

Tags: litespeed

I have used openwysiwyg v1.4.7 as for my dynamic website to have contents what we see is what you get. Well i'm not using any opensource CMS or any tools too make a website. I'm building my own site in core php.

Every thing is working fine offline(openwysiwyg_v1.4.7 editor image selection too) and everything works fine online too except WYSIWYG image selection part that is uploaded previously or can be uploaded for selection.

It gives this error:

> 406 not acceptable this request is not acceptable Powered By LiteSpeed Web Server
>     LiteSpeed Technologies is not responsible for administration and contents of this web site!

I tried going through many forums, found that we need to work with .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

But this didn't solve my problem.

What exactly is causing the issue. This problem doesn't allow openwysiwyg_v1.4.7 editor to select image, every other part of openwysiwyg_v1.4.7 editor is working fine.

Comment: This is an issue with litespeed, not PHP. Suggest move to ServerFault where you may be able to get more help.

Comment: thank you @Rudi Visser for your quick response. Well what shall i do ?  I didn't get the last sentence . do you mean i should search serverFault in google? please don't mind for not understanding exactly.

Comment: ServerFault is another StackExchange website: http://www.serverfault.com/