# Apache 2 multiviews and 406 error for image/* request

Tags: php, apache, http, apache2, multiview

The client is requesting an image:

```
GET /api/2.0/users/80.png HTTP/1.1
Host: learnwithecho.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: image/* <------------------------------ HERE'S THE IMPORTANT PART
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Echo/1.0.16.1 CFNetwork/672.0.2 Darwin/12.5.0
```

And I have a script at api/2.0/users.php (yes, PATH_INFO is on)

```
...
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$user = User::getUserWithID($filename);
header("Location: ".$user->getImageURL());
exit(0);
```

But Apache or PHP is trying to act like it knows me... and it don't. It assumes a PHP script couldn't possibly want to respond with a image/png and it throws a `406 Not Acceptable` error.

Can I successfully configure Apache/PHP to respond to this request?

Comment: Related topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084283/406-server-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/archives/2005/04/beware-of-apaches-multiviews

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233146/406-error-not-acceptable-openwysiwyg-v1-4-7-while-image-selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I successfully configure Apache/PHP to respond to this request?

Yes. Just use the [`MultiviewsMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch) directive to tell Apache that it can serve `.php` files regardless of whether their MIME type is compatible with the `Accept` header:

```
<Files "*.php">
    MultiviewsMatch Any
</Files>
```

From the docs, the effect is as follows:

> You may finally allow `Any` extensions to match, even if `mod_mime` doesn't recognize the extension.

Answer (score -1):

You need to either disable MultiViews in this context or create dummy copies of your script with extensions that tell mod_negotiation what kinds of mimetypes it can generate (not really recommended)

as-is, mod_negotiation has no way to probe for what types can be generated by users.php.

Comment: Or can I disable mod_negotiation for this request?

Comment: Something like:
<Location /api/2.0/users/>
  Options -MultiViews
</Location>

Or in regex form if you need to know the extension, tolerate other versions, etc.

Comment: If you only have access to .htaccess, this will work: <FilesMatch "users">Options -MultiViews</FilesMatch>

Comment: NOTE: See https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1585#issuecomment-28416667 about `[UIImageView+AFNetworking setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url]`