# htaccess rewrite fails when the http accept header changes

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my .htaccess file I use a simple redirect rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule SMS SMS.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This works for a simple request with a HTTP-header like

```
Accept: text/html,*/*
Accept-language: en
```

But for requests with a header with another Accept-header like

```
Accept: bla/bla
Accept-language: en
```

I get a `HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable` error.

I can get it to work, adding this to my `.htaccess` file

```
<Files *>
ForceType bla/bla
</Files>
```

But I'm searching for a solution that accepts any `Accept-header` currently I need to know the exact spelling, something like this fails

```
ForceType */*
```

Btw. When I access the page directly (`http://example.com/SMS.php`) without the rewrite rule it works, independent of the access-header.

Comment: The server sends a 406 error when it detects that it cannot send back any type the client requests from the server. You should not return a data stream with a different mime type that the client cannot (or doesn't want to) receive.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I know this, but currently I need to redirect in any case. But thanks anyway

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169337/apache-2-multiviews-and-406-error-for-image-request

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks, didn't know `MultiviewsMatch Any`, but sadly it doesn't work